# Can Gradle tests live peacefully with old style test projects

Tags: android, testing, ant, gradle, automated-tests

So in the olden days, when you wanted to do tests in Android, you used to make a new test project like:

```
RealProject
|-- AndroidManifest.xml
|-- src
|   |-- com
|   |   |-- example
|   |   |   |-- Foo.java
`-- tests
    `-- AndroidManifest
        `-- src
            `-- com
                `-- example
                    `-- Foo.java
```

Meaning the tests were in a project that lived somewhere, by convention in the tests folder.

In the new build system, if you are migrating from an existing android project (and must support developers who are using Eclipse and thus ant), you're suggested by the [New Build System User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) to add the following so it maintains the project structure from the old version.

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

This is all fine and good until you try to write the tests. Given the above structure, you're meant to put tests in

```
RealProject
`-- tests
    `-- java
        `-- com
            `-- example
                `-- FooTest.java
```

The difference between the two is that Gradle expects the subdirectory in `tests` to be `java` but ant expects it to be `src`.

So how can I merge these two systems together. The goal being that I can run unit tests from *either* Gradle or ant. Gradle seems like it should be more flexible than the ant test system but no combination of things i've tried to put in the sourceSets seems to work. It almost looks like instrumentTest is not a normal sourceSet or something like that. I've tried:

- Symlink `tests/java` to `tests/src`
- Add a block like `instrumentTest { java.srcDirs = ['src'] }` with trying every combination of the `*.srcDirs` I could make from the main sourceSet example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do this:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['tests/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['tests/assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Then drop your test manifest in `tests/`. Gradle will ignore it, but Ant/ADT can use it.

Create `tests/project.properties` and point the tested project to `../`

In Eclipse, you can open a project that's inside another one, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yup, works like a champ. More generally, given an existing Ant/Eclipse test project that works, adjust the `build.gradle` to  have the `instrumentTest` source set point at proper directories in the test project, and leave the test project otherwise alone. Many thanks!

Comment: the only issue may be if you have the tested and test project side by side. I don't think Studio will like having the test folders outside of the project root. In that case you could make the parent folder the project.

Comment: Ah, that's a Studio thing, and I have not tried this particular set of projects in Studio. Gradle itself doesn't mind where it is, and I do have my tested and test projects as peers.

Comment: Thanks, guys this allows me to complete the rest of my customizing to make gradle work with Eclipse ADT 22.3..nice work :)